# Facebook php sdk 3.2.3 retrieve post by id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have successfully gone through the Oauth process and posted to my wall using the code below, but I need to check that a post exists by it's id and I just can't seem to find the way to do it anywhere?!

This is the entire process so far, ripped pretty much straight from the Facebook Dev site.

```
require_once(APPPATH."libraries/facebook/facebook.php");

$config = array('appId' => APP_ID, 'secret' => APP_SECRET);
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();

if($user_id)
{
    try
    {
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO RETRIEVE A POST, RATHER THAN POST ONE!
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('link' => 'www.example.com', 'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'));
        echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions'));
        header('Location: ' . $login_url);
    }   
}
else
{
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'publish_actions'));
    header('Location: ' . $login_url);
}
```

I have tried various intelligent guesses and looked at the graph docs but it's all greek to me! API's are not my strong point, but I managed integrate Twitters without missing a beat in about 5 minutes.

Before anyone mentions that I'm not using v4, my server doesn't have PHP 5.4 yet. And I can't change that.

Comment: Why do you need to check whether the post “exists” if you just got positive feedback from the API that it was indeed created successfully …?

Comment: The two aren't connected... in the finished product it will check for the post from a saved id, and if it can't find it will remove the the saved id. The fact that my example posts successfully was just to show that what I have in its current form works - the posting happens somewhere else in the project. Sorry if that's confusing.

Comment: Unless the post visibility is “public”, you will not be able to read it via API without `read_stream` permission. (And that you will not get granted in login review for this purpose.)

Comment: So assume the post visibility is public, or that I can get read_stream permissions granted, how would I do it in this example?

Comment: Simply by making an API request for that post id.

Comment: But how?! This is my question! How do I need to change this line: `$ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('link' => 'www.example.com', 'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'));` to retrieve a post?

Comment: `$foo = $facebook->api('/1234567890')` – how else?

Comment: That's all I needed to know! The answer's easy to the person who knows it. Thank you.